# What size of capacitors do I need for 60V DC input?

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-divider, high-voltage

I'm designing a DAQ with 8 analog inputs (0-60V DC).

I would like to ask what size of capacitors should I use, as shown in the picture?

This Op-Amp costs 4$, is there another cheaper Op-Amp you recommend instead?

The picture below is a 1/12 voltage divider with Op-Amp and it will be X8 (for each input).

[image: 1/12 Voltage Divider]

Comment: Further: product recommendation is considered off topic on this site.

Comment: Do you even know what the capacitors are supposed to do? Because I feel like you just threw them in without knowing what they are and if they are actually needed or not. Otherwise you would have provided some performance specification you are aiming for at which point the question changes from one that is unanswerable to one that is almost self-answering.

Comment: That partial schematic showed up a couple of days ago with a similar question. I seem to remember a comment asking what you expected the capacitor to do. If you have an explanation then edit it into your question. The product recommendation part of your question could get it closed.

Comment: Last: The clamping diodes may be superfluous as the may be already be integrated within the opamp (check its datasheet)

Comment: It’s not a 1/12 voltage divider, but 1/13.

Comment: Also, your chosen opamp can only process up to 2V common mode at the input with a 5V supply. It is not rail-to-rail input. Anything above 26V will saturate the input –

Comment: Capacitor value depends on your main signal frequency. If the main signal is low, suppose 50 Hz and some noise with it, then you may use 10 uF. Because of coronavirus, my oscilloscope is 250 km far away from me, so I can't say accurate value.

Comment: And you don't need an optocoupler. Just use 1-watt resistors as current will be almost 0.5 amp.

Comment: @SadatRafi ok thanks! I have 8 inputs should i use 4 X TLC2272 or 2 X TLC2274?

Comment: TLC2274 is better to use.

Comment: @SadatRafi ok thanks alot Sadat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TLC2272 rail-to-rail Op-Amp. It's available in Ali-express (I bought it from there). 
And you have to use a 100-volt polyester capacitor. It's non-polar. [Ali express link is here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33058859432.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.4d66324ded8MNQ&algo_pvid=faf145b4-0da4-46c6-bdbb-32730515cd8d&algo_expid=faf145b4-0da4-46c6-bdbb-32730515cd8d-0&btsid=0ab6f82115850773609895534e5166&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_). Don't use tiny ceramic capacitors. They will explode. I've tested that.

Comment: Please don't source components from ali express. Use digikey, mouser, newark, or another reputable distributor.

Comment: And why do you need a 100V capacitor? I see no purpose to the left capacitor being there. At all.

Comment: As your input is 60 volt, the capacitor needs to be rated more than 60 volts. Usually, you will find 16 / 32 / 48 / 60 / 100 / 220 /480 volt capacitors. That's why I suggested 100 volts.

Comment: Maybe he wanna smooth the input. It's up to his wish.

Comment: @SadatRafi Except it won't smooth anything. That's my point. Having a the left cap there to try and smooth the waveform when the right cap is already present is like having a tank that already has steel armour and trying to protect it by placing paper in front of it. In both cases you need a LOT of paper/capacitance to make any difference when you already have a much more effective and practical right there, already installed.

Comment: @Sadat Rafi, Hi thank you for the link, which size do i need?

Comment: @Sadat Rafi, another question, I have 8 inputs should i use 4 X TLC2272 or 2 X TLC2274?

Comment: Another thing, do i need to place a optocoupler after the Op-Amp? or is the Op-Amp enough?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help, im sharing with you my final block diagram -

[image: 8 Digital I/O & 8 Analog I DAQ Device]

Comment: Roy, this is part of your question so you should have posted it there, not as an answer. Can you move it and delete this?